# Can I add new yeast to a dough I made with dead yeast?

Tags: dough, yeast

I prepared bread dough that didn't rise. I then tested the yeast I used and apperantly they are dead.
I bought new yeast and I still have the dough in the fridge. Can I mix in the new yeast to the dough, or do I need to make a new batch?

Comment: I’ve never tried kneading the yeast in directly.  But I did once make a half batch of dough with triple the yeast, and mixed that in with the original.  But it was more a batter (baked in a loaf pan) than a dough that required kneading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can knead it in and it will still work. I've forgotten yeast when making bread and added it in at the end, it still rose and I got a good result.

How you do it depends on the type of yeast. 'Easy Bake' or 'Instant' yeast is the same strain of yeast, but finer grained, this can be kneaded in directly, I would scatter some on the top, knead it in, then scatter some more, repeating until it is all incorporated.

Regular yeast has much bigger grains, mixing it in dry may not work well, I suggest you dissolve it in a small amount of water first, then pour in on the counter and knead that in. It's messy but it will work, you will then need to knead in a bit more flour to get it back to the right balance.

Comment: Yeast that’s in smaller bits is often sold as ‘instant yeast’

Comment: Thanks Joe, I've added that in. There are several marketing names for it.

Comment: Considering the dough has been in fridge, it will have to be heated up or more time given for the yeast to do its thing.